# Displaying Kannada characters fetched from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, mysql-python

I have English and [Kannada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada) characters stored in a MySQL table in the following format:
There are two columns in the table:

```
IBM        ಐಬಿಎಮ್  
Microsoft  ಮಿಕ್ರೊಸೊಫ್ಟ್
```

When I run the select statement for Kannada characters in MySQL Workbench, I get output in proper Kannada prompt...
But, when I try to access these Kannada characters through a Python program (using MySQLdb module) and display them, they display as question marks ("???? ???").

Could someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please provide your python code. Try to add # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- at the top of your python code.

Comment: Here is my code..As you can see,some kannada text I have typed in into the code(with the help of other software) is displayed properly..Also,I can print unicode characters without any problem..

Comment: import MySQLdb as mdb
import unidecode
predict={
   'a':('ಅವರು'
}
try:
    con=mdb.connect('localhost','root','user1','database1',use_unicode="True")
cur=con.cursor()
q2="select ksubject from ksubjects where subject like "%IBM%"
cur.execute(q2)
print q2k=cur.fetchall()[0]
print k[0],unidecode.unidecode(k[0])

Comment: I have also added  # -- coding: UTF-8 -- to the python file..But,it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just set database collection that field "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: I did that..but it didn't work..Probably the problem is that characters are being stored in ASCII format in the file from which I am loading the characters using load data infile..